# Python: loop dictionary keys and values in regex condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to create clusters based on certain keywords.
In my attempt solution, I use a dictionary to cluster lists of keywords with a key (or cluster name). Then I try to .loc the rows using the keywords and add the respective cluster name (dictionary key) in a new column.
The solution attempt looks like this:

```
test = train_df.copy()
test['workcenter_cluster'] = np.nan

cluster_dict ={'machining': ['trim-machining', 'machining', 'routing'], 'form': ['cold-form', 'form', 'form', 'form-assembly', 'hot-form', 'shear'],
               'manual_ops': ['fill', 'assembly', 'trim', 'cut', 'lubrication'], 'inspect': ['test', 'inspect'], 'finish': ['finishing', 'paint', 'cure-paint'],
               'oven': ['oven', 'bond-cure'], 'treatment': ['treament', 'treatment', 'chem-treatment'], 'rwk': 'rework'}
cluster_items = cluster_dict.items()

for items, key in zip(cluster_items, cluster_dict):
    test.loc[test.workcenter_class.str.contains((rf"\b{items}\b"), case=False, regex=True), 'workcenter_cluster'] = key
```

However, I got the following:

**error: bad character range m-a at position 45**

Can you please explain to me why the error occurs, and if you're kind enough can you please correct my solution?

Example dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd-e', 'f-g', 'h']})

  column1
0       a
1       b
2       c
3     d-e
4     f-g
5       h
```

Expected outcome:

```
  column1 clusters_column1
0       a   cluster a to c
1       b   cluster a to c
2       c   cluster a to c
3     d-e   cluster d to g
4     f-g   cluster d to g
5       h      cluster h-z
```

Comment: The error is because in regex, doing `m-a`, that happens in the word `form-assembly`, is not allowed. It is interpreted as the character interval between m and a, except this interval does not exist (like if you look for a number greater than 100 and lower than 10, not really possible). that said, please share some input data (e.g. `test.head(10)`), and also do a `print(items)` in your loop, I'm not sure it is what you expect :)

Comment: Looks like you need to escape the content of items. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape